# Vim plugins not working on Mac OS X in terminal?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I am trying to use the EasyMotion plugin in vim but for some reason it's not working. I remapped my leader key to `,` but whenever I press `,w`, it just moves forward one word i.e. it seems like it's not detecting the leader key. Any advice?

Comment: Do you use the default Vim? Is it a `<leader>` problem or an EasyMotion problem? Why the *Linux* tag?

Comment: in EasyMotion all mappings start with `<leader><leader>` by default.